# What are the most frequently cited textbooks in the physics literature?

Tags: publications, citations, books, physics

What are the most frequently cited textbooks in the physics literature?

**Note**: I am not looking for guesses, but answers supported by citations data. What are some good physics citations databases?

Comment: You actually ask two questions, one is textbooks and the other is data base. Which one do you want to ask? There are many physics subfields. Do you want absolutely the most frequently cited or relatively most frequently cited?

Comment: If we can go for indirect citations the Principia will probably be in the top of the list.

Comment: Citation databases would draw their data from published research papers. Published research papers don't normally cite textbooks. In fact, one of the most frequent signs of a kook paper is that rather than citing the current research literature, it cites other sources such as textbooks or century-old papers.

Comment: @BenCrowell: Citing century-old papers isn't a sign it's "a kook paper", is it? I've seen that before.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers What is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer you might be looking for lies in [this recent Nature News article on the most cited scholarly works](http://www.nature.com/news/the-top-100-papers-1.16224) of all time.

Specifically, for evidence supported by real data I'd look at [the Google Scholar top 100 spreadsheet file](http://www.nature.com/polopoly_fs/7.21245!/file/GoogleScholartop100.xlsx)

In this, you'll find Google Scholar citation data for physics-related books like:

- [*Principles of optics: electromagnetic theory of propagation, interference and diffraction of light*](https://archive.org/details/PrinciplesOfOptics) (1959) with 49132 citations
- [*Classical electrodynamics*](https://archive.org/details/ClassicalElectrodynamics) (1962) with 36945 citations
- [*Physics of semiconductor devices*](https://archive.org/details/PhysicsOfSemiconductorDevices) (1981) with 33789 citations

It depends what you define as a 'textbook' though, I suppose...

Comment: Since OP asked "frequency" rather than the raw number of total citations, it might make sense to divide the number of citations to a book by its age. In this case, only a few, if at all, would beat *Quantum computation and quantum information* by M. A. Nielsen and I. L. Chuang: http://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=ZP0eZ94AAAAJ&citation_for_view=ZP0eZ94AAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C

Comment: Are those all the physics-related ones?

Comment: I'd pick through the list yourself to determine that; I'm a biologist, not a physicist so I only picked the ones I thought were definitely physics-y.